# How to cache Facebook friends list using iPhone application

Tags: ios, facebook, caching, indexing, fb-graph

I am developing iPhone application which contains the facebook connect as part of it. I am using third party API `FBGraph` to retrieve the Facebook friends list.

Currently my problem is that, when there is huge number of friends in list, it takes much time to load those. Its loading again and again when I navigating through the pages and come again.

In order to avoid this, i am trying to use caching concept. But I am currently stuck with this. I dont have clue on how the Facebook friends list can be cached.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to cache the data in IOS.

- You can store the response in a file and use that file whenever you require.
- You can store it sqlite db  using core data / standalone

and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Just load user friends at app start and then use it all the time.